# How to get tick marks between the bars in R?

Tags: r, graphics, graph, plot, bar-chart

I'd like to get the tick marks between consumption bars, such as in http://hante.home.xs4all.nl/plugwise_dagoverzicht_281009_2.jpg.

It's more logical to get the consumption between two dates, or two times...

However, I don't see how to do that in R. Anybody?

I do have such an example table, called data:

```
       date  nombre  delta 
 2014-02-01       0      0 
 2014-02-08     120    120 
 2014-02-15     205     85 
 2014-02-22     280     75 
 2014-02-29     350     70
```

The code I managed so far to write down is:

```
data$date <- as.POSIXct(data$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
data <- data[-2]
barplot(height=data[,2], names=data[,1], las=2)
```

But the "ticks" are just below the bars... as you can see on https://i.stack.imgur.com/vilgz.jpg.

Comment: Probably no one will help unless you provide much more context: what code+data have you used to create your bar chart? How have you tried to create that axis and how hasn't it worked?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any code whatsoever. How is your data represented? How are you plotting the bars?

If you are using package `lattice`'s `barchart(..., horizontal=FALSE)`, you can manually provide new axis tickslabels using the argument `scales=list(x=list(at=seq_len(numBars+1) - 0.5, labels=yourLabels)))` where `numBars` is the number of bins on your x-axis. See `?barchart`.

If you are using the more primitive `barplot`, you can draw an offset axis yourself:

```
mids <- barplot(x, axisnames=FALSE)
axis(1, at = mids - (mids[2]-mids[1])/2, labels = yourLabels)
```

Either way, obviously you can shift to the right instead by changing offset signs, or add both outside ticks for `numBins`+1 labels.

**EDIT**: With the code+data you added in your edit:

```
mids <- barplot(height=data[,2], axisnames=FALSE)
axis(1, at = mids - (mids[2]-mids[1])/2, labels = data[,1], las=2)
```

or e.g. writing it and adding an end date:

```
mstep <- (mids[2] - mids[1]) / 2
axis(1, at=c(mids[1] - mstep, mids + mstep), labels=c(data[,1], endDate), las=2)
```

Comment: Thanks A LOT for your answer. A priori, I was looking for a base graphics, not a Lattice one. But if I have to change because my request is not feasible otherwise, I'll do it... I'll test your answer a bit later, and come back to you.

Comment: No problem. `barplot` is base graphics.

Comment: And is a similar solution to yours possible with barplot?

Comment: In your edit section, the first code works perfectly. The second not, as you can see on http://imgur.com/0A9Kk35: I don't get the last 2 labels. Any idea why?

Comment: The ticks are in the right places, but the last two labels seem to be getting lost. Evaluate `data[,1]`, `endDate`, and `c(data[,1], endDate)` to see what goes wrong.